# Immutable classes and copy constructors

Tags: c++11, immutability, copy-constructor

I'm making a framework which will read a [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/)'s XML file and the resulting object (tpp::File) will be pure immutable (no setters or copy constructors/assignment operators). Basically, it kind of uses the [builder pattern](https://jlordiales.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/the-builder-pattern-in-practice/) idea, but instead of having 2 objects with the same attributes, I'll have one with the main attributes and another that will "wrap" it.

```
// Represents a Tiled's TMX file. This object is immutable.
class TILEDPP_API File final
{
public:
    File() = default;
    File(tpp::File&&) = default;
    File(const tpp::File&) = delete;
    File(const tpp::Path& path, tpp::FileMetadata& metadata);

    File& operator = (tpp::File&&) = default;
    File& operator = (const tpp::File&) = delete;

    const tpp::Path& getPath() const;
    const tpp::Header& getHeader() const;
    const tpp::Layers& getLayers() const;
    const tpp::TileSets& getTileSets() const;

private:
    const tpp::Path m_path;
    tpp::FileMetadata m_metadata; // Should be const!
};

// Represents the content of a Tiled's TMX file (header, sets, layers etc). 
// This struct is non-copyable due to its HUGE size.
struct TILEDPP_API FileMetadata final
{
    FileMetadata() = default;
    FileMetadata(tpp::FileMetadata&&) = default;
    FileMetadata(const tpp::FileMetadata&) = delete;

    FileMetadata& operator = (FileMetadata&&) = default;
    FileMetadata& operator = (const FileMetadata&) = delete;

    tpp::Header header;
    tpp::Layers layers;
    tpp::TileSets sets;
};
```

Then, somewhere in the file creation process, we'll have this:

```
tpp::File FileReader::read(const std::string& path)
{
    tpp::FileMetadata metadata = m_parser.parseMetadata(path);

    return tpp::File(path, metadata);
}
```

The above snippet will use the `File(const tpp::Path& path, tpp::FileMetadata& metadata)` constructor, as expected. **However**, if we make tpp::File's tpp::FileMetadata const, it will try to use the `File(const tpp::File&)` constructor instead, which is **deleted**. Why does it even happen?!

For reference, the project can be found [here](https://github.com/YvesHenri/TiledPlusPlus). Any thoughts are also much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> it will try to use the `File(const tpp::File&)` constructor instead

Instead is the wrong word.

As well is the right word.

Prior to C++17, you are creating a temporary `File` and returning a move-constructed copy from the function.  (This move construction may be elided, and in C++17 there is no move constructed copy any more).

`FileMetaData` does not support a move from `FileMetadata const&&)`.  So your `=default` in `File(File&&)` doesn't work; no default implementation can work.

---

Objects cannot be both immutable and practically movable-from.

Immutable objects cannot be practically moved-from in C++; while they are immutable during destruction, move-from happens *before destruction*, when they must be immutable.  So you cannot "tear out their state" and move it somewhere else.

I state this, because you appear to **want** to support move-from:

```
File(tpp::File&&) = default;
File& operator = (tpp::File&&) = default;
```

If you want move-from, `File` *cannot* be immutable.  If you want immutable, then `File` cannot be moved-from.

So, suppose you want to keep immutability.

---

Make those `=delete`, then change

```
return tpp::File(path, metadata)
```

to

```
return {std::move(path), std::move(metadata)};
```

and change

```
File(const tpp::Path& path, tpp::FileMetadata& metadata);
```

to

```
File(tpp::Path&& path, tpp::FileMetadata&& metadata);
```

and your code compiles.

To call `read`, store the return value in a `File&&` or a `auto&&` -- an rvalue reference to the temporary `read` returns.

Note you cannot store this returned `File` in a varible of longer lifetime, as that requires moving from the `File`, which immutable objects do not permit.

---

Alternatively, back off on immutability.  Make it immutable **except for moving**.

Objects that are immutable **except for moving** do not store their data as `const`, because they mutate it when they move.  Every other method on them is `const`.

Comment: Hi, @Yakk! Thanks for your reply! Could you please enlighten me on this: `FileMetaData does not support a move from FileMetadata const&&). So your =default in File(File&&) doesn't work; no default implementation can work.`? Also, how does "adding support" for move-from requires it to *delete* the move constructor/assigment operator?!

Comment: @YvesHenri Where did you see "adding support"?  Who are you quoting?  Your design cannot support move-from; you want immutability, you cannot have move support.  The initial comments about move support are me deducing you *want* move support; I simply state you cannot have it.  The `=default` was actually not implementing them; so I made it explicit that it was `=delete`d.  I then changed the return statement to construct in-place instead of move into return value.  This has serious limitations, as I describe before the final line.  After the final line, I say "well, here is another solution".